# Need to create a view for the following scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

There is an Athelete table consisting of 4 columns.

```
AtheleteID - Primary Key varchar(20)
name - varchar(20)
country - varchar(20)
rank - integer
```

And another Participate table where the above atheletes participate on events. consisting of 4 columns.

```
AtheleteID - Foreign Key varchar(20)
EventID - Composite Primary Key varchar(20)
EventDate - date
position - integer
```

Question:
I need to create a view named TopAtheletes. 
View attributes are AtheleteID,name,rank and the number of times they have achieved position (1,2 or 3)

How do i create the view? 
I'm stuck on querying for the number of times the athelete has achieved position 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: also please share the code you tried.

Comment: Also what will if an athlete has multiple entries in Participate table, what will be rank in result view? Can you please provide sample result?

Comment: The database i'm using is oracle.

Comment: [The expected result is here](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn%3Aaaid%3Ascds%3AUS%3Abc4a5d64-6cfb-4ac8-b7d2-271f27baaf05)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first count the no of times they achieved the top positions and then can join that with athlete table -

```
CREATE VIEW VW_ATHLETE_INFO
AS
SELECT A.AtheleteID
      ,A.name
      ,A.rank
      ,P.cnt
FROM Athelete
JOIN (SELECT AtheleteID, COUNT(CASE WHEN position <= 3 THEN 1 END) CNT
      FROM Participate
      GROUP BY AtheleteID) P ON A.AtheleteID = P.AtheleteID
```